# Can players remove curses from their cursed items?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, curses

The DMG has entries for cursed items, which I like to slip into otherwise random loot every now and then just to get on my player's nerves.

Can a player remove the curse from a cursed item using *Remove Curse*, or some other way? If so, how does that work mechanically? Is the item still enchanted, must the caster roll something VS item creator DC?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### *Remove curse* just lets you get rid of the cursed item

While *remove curse* will eliminate curses put onto an item, it does nothing about curses built into a cursed item. It just lets the user get rid of the item (where cursed items usually prevent that).

Aside from that, *wish* **might** be able to do it. It’s not a listed effect, though, so troubles abound there. I certainly wouldn’t be making any use of *wish* with a DM who actually included a cursed item.

Just, a side note: have you ever discussed these random cursed items with your players? I personally despise them; I don’t think they add anything interesting to the game, and tend to muck up the story and plot with pointless sidetracking. Cursed items as macguffins? Cool. That sword in the dragon’s horde that randomly prevents you from continuing on your quest until you trek back to town? Not interested.

Plenty of other players are, I realize; if yours are, there is no problem. But frankly I don’t really think “just to get on my player’s nerves” is a particularly good reason to do anything in D&D. Honestly, if it’s detracting from their play experience, it really just seems rude. After all, your players are committing some portion of their free time to play your game; wasting it indicates that you don’t value their time. So I recommend checking on that.

Comment: Even Matrim Cauthon has had to deal with cursed items. Bad things happen, players get greeding. Drunken_Guy isn't rude for using cursed items. I'm sure by "to get on my players' nerves" he means "to add an element of humanity into my players." I'm sure his players give him a harder time than he gives them. Now I shall return to you your soap box.

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild Note the difference there: Matrim encountered  planned, plot-relevant cursed items. Jordan certainly had a verbose, rambling style, but even he didn't waste readers' time reading about how Mat was cursed into uselessness until he side-tracked to a never-again-mentioned mystic's house to undo the curse - which is how random cursed items often wind up. As usual, it's really just a special case of good DMing vs. bad DMing. And while I have a personal problem with such random cursed items, I don't consider them badwrongfun if everyone's on board. Just make sure they are.